# How to implement SSL Pinning on SFSafariViewController?

Tags: ios, security, oauth-2.0, ssl-certificate, sfsafariviewcontroller

In my app, I've set up SSL Pinning on all my REST requests with the help of [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#security-policy). This helps prevent MITM attacks. When I test my app using Charles proxy as the "man in the middle", the requests fail as expected. However, this is not the case for my login flow (Oauth 2.0) via SFSafariViewController. That is because ... this process of logging in is unrelated to AFNetworking.

I believe the problem could be solved if there was a way to achieve SSL Pinning on SFSafariViewController.

1) Is there a way to do this? I could not find anything online about this. 
2) What are some ways people go about solving this problem? It seems like it is a security issue.

Comment: I am curious whether you have found anything interesting on this subject?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't recall ever finding a solution to this! It has been quite some time ago that I looked into this though

Comment: @GabrielPires have you found a solution to this? I am in the same situation right now.

Comment: @AuRis, sorry bud! I haven't taken a look at this issue since I posted the question. At the time, I unfortunately hadn't found a solution. It's been nearly two years now though, maybe someone has found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

To me the following comment makes sense.
there is no way to do any SSL pinning in SFSafariViewController, for two reasons:

1. The **SFSafariViewController** class does not provide any API for
   customizing SSL validation and handling authentication challenges.
2. When used, the **SFSafariViewController** is actually run in a separate
   process and the app's code has no access to it at all. Hence
   swizzling does not affect the **SFSafariViewController** as it only
   happens in the app's process.

Reference:-
https://github.com/datatheorem/TrustKit/issues/163

Answer (score 0):

You could use `WKWebView` (WebKit) and create your own version of `SFSafariViewController` that has your pinning for where you use `SFSafariViewController`, but you can not certificate pin in `SFSafariViewController`.  If you are using `SFSafariViewController` for downloading configuration profiles, then you are stuck, no cert pinning allowed and `WKWebView` will not "store" configuration profiles for installation, only Safari.app and `SFSafariViewController` can do that, to my knowledge.